# Cannot mount USB disks due to "not authorized" error

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I have Ubuntu 12.04 (.2?) installed. I don't plan to need GUI after setup so I modified the grub to start in console. However, whenever I want to start up GUI I need to type `startx`. Simple/basic stuff. However I seem to be hitting a snag:

I am having trouble mounting/accessing USB flash drives in the GUI I started in the console. "Unable to mount location - not authorized".

Seemed like it should be an easy fix, but can't figure out how I'm overlooking it. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

*I am experiencing the same issue in the same scenery, modified  my Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS in order to start in console and I start my XFCE via startxfce4, the same problem mounting external drives/usb. Hope someone drop an answer for a fix.*

Meanwhile, I deliver this workaround for future reference:

We can gain access to the unmounted usb/external drives by dropping the next command in a terminal.

```
sudo -S palimpsest
```

***I know that we should use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` but if you do it that way you'll receive an error as in the next screenshot:***

[image]

After providing our user password, the Disk Utility will be presented so that we can choose the drive/usb memory that we wish to mount and gain access to its files via file explorer (nautilus or any other) for read/write.

[image]

BUT! For that purpose we need to click in the link provided in the lower right corner with the label "Mount Point: Mounted at /media/DriveName"

This also works for my additional SATA Drives, which got compromised after the change that I made to my grub in order to boot in console (text) mode. No. This change isn't reverted by removing the changes I made to my GRUB.

Let's wait for an answer and meanwhile I hope this works for you the same as it does for me and may help future visitors.

Good luck!

Comment: I couldn't find a fix and finished reinstalling. The problems started incrementally increasing and at a certain point it wasn't able to run a simple task. However I let this answer here just for reference for a backup or something in case that somebody has to reinstall as I did. My backups however, were on Ubuntu ONE so I didn't lose anything. Good luck!

Comment: `gksu palimpsest` and `su`+`nautilus` was the only thing that worked for me. Lately nautilus and GNOME are really buggy, ffs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work for anyone else but discovered my `/etc/mtab` file was not right. It was missing the following line (tested-- behavior the same if the line is malformed):

```
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/<Username>/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=<Username> 0 0
```

Comment: The post dropped the Username ref in the home path and before the 0 0